# In VS2010 c++, how does one source file reference a user-defined variable type defined in another source file?

Tags: visual-c++, typedef, declaration, visual-studio-2010

In VS2010 c++, how does one source file reference a user-defined variable type defined in another source file?

I had a large source file containing a typedef statement in its global section. 
Following is that statement:

```
typedef struct tagDRAWITEMSTRUCT_itemData {
    HICON hIcon[3];
    int ndxPlayer;      // Allowable values are 0:NumPlayers. 
      .
      .
  } DRAWITEMSTRUCT_itemData;
```

For convenience I recently divided my source file into two files.
There are references to this data type in both files, but cannot figure out how to 
reference instances of this variable type in both files.  Following is a 
list of plausible solutions that DO NOT WORK:

(1)  Defining the variable type in one file and simply referencing it in the other file, to wit:

```
 DRAWITEMSTRUCT_itemData *foo   // As a function arg or local variable definition. 

 extern DRAWITEMSTRUCT_itemData *foo   // As a global declaration
```

(2)  Defining the variable type in one file and attempting to declare it in the other file using any of the following global statements:

```
 extern tagDRAWITEMSTRUCT_itemData;
 extern tagDRAWITEMSTRUCT_itemData DRAWITEMSTRUCT_itemData;
 extern typedef struct tagDRAWITEMSTRUCT_itemData;   
 extern typedef DRAWITEMSTRUCT_itemData;
```

(3)  Placing the variable type definition in each function that uses it, which, of course, can't work at all for function arguments.

In the past I have resolved this obstacle by using a class definition -- a royal pain for simple structures.

Comment: I just found a simple solution that appears to work:

Comment: I just found a simple solution that appears to work:  
I cut a portion of the original large source file containing a bunch of subfunctions referenced by the main dialog proc function. 
I pasted the cut text into a new file, which I saved as w/ extension ".h".  
At the site of the excision in the original source file I added an #include statement referencing said "header file".

To my surprise, this appears to work.  I thought I had tried this solution long ago, without success.  

Nonetheless, I would be interested in anyone having a more direct solution.

Answer (score 1):

If this was in your *source.cpp*

```
//Now in source.h

typedef struct tagDRAWITEMSTRUCT_itemData 
{
    HICON hIcon[3];
    int ndxPlayer;      // Allowable values are 0:NumPlayers. 
      .
      .
  } DRAWITEMSTRUCT_itemData;
```

it should now go into your *source.h*

And the new *source2.cpp* should also include *source.h* to use `tagDRAWITEMSTRUCT_itemData` typedef.

Answer (score 0):

You should put all the type definitions (i.e. `typedef`, but also `class` & `struct` & `enum` ...) and function and variables declarations in a common header file, which you would `#include`  from your source code files.